# Why isn't my fetched blob audio file getting played? I'm using React Native Track Player

Tags: javascript, react-native, blob, fetch-api, react-native-track-player

I'm currently using the React Native Track Player for playing audio, and it plays local audio tracks fine. When I fetch it through my private api it correctly gets the audio object in blob form - here is what the console returns when I logged it.

`{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "F7F673C8-A5E6-4941-AD52-7EBA03F47290", "name": "9to5.mp3", "offset": 0, "size": 8035972, "type": "audio/mpeg"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "F7F673C8-A5E6-4941-AD52-7EBA03F47290", "name": "9to5.mp3", "offset": 0, "size": 8035972, "type": "audio/mpeg"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"accept-ranges": "bytes", "connection": "keep-alive", "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"9to5.mp3\"", "content-length": "8035972", "content-type": "audio/mpeg", "date": "Thu, 15 Dec 2022 01:50:39 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=60"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "http://localhost:8080/downloadFile/9to5.mp3"}`

I converted this blob into a url so I'm confused why this wouldn't work. Here is my code -
`

```
export const FetchGetFile = async () => {
  let res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/downloadFile/9to5.mp3');
  console.log(res);
  const data = await res.blob();
  let bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  const track = {
    url: bloburl,
    title: 'a',
    artist: 'b',
    duration: 166,
  };
  TrackPlayer.add(track)
};
```

`

Inside of FetchGetFile() I have substituted a local audio file in the url property in track with `require(./song.mp3)` and this works, so I think it has something to do with the audio blob url or react native track player.

Answer (score 0):

Use RN fetch blob https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

```js
RNFetchBlob.config({
  // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
  // this is much more performant.
  fileCache: true,
})
  .fetch("GET", "http://www.example.com/file/example.zip", {
    //some headers ..
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // the temp file path
    console.log("The file saved to ", res.path());
  });
```